# Wrong position of annotations in a stacked bar chart (Google Chart API)

Tags: google-visualization

I have a stacked bar chart with annotations which sums the values. The annotations are always at the end of the bar, but when there isn't a value for the last data row (I) the annotation is at the beginning and I don't know how to fix it.

```
var dataArray = [
    ["Date", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", {role: 'annotation'}],
    ["7.08.2015", 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 10],
    ["6.08.2015", 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 1, 0, 7, 18],
    ["5.08.2015", 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 11]
];
```

[Demo and code at JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hurik/f2cwmvg6/)

[image: Image of the problem ...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround ... added a new data column, with the name Total, is has the same value as the annotation:

```
var dataArray = [
    ["Date", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "Total", {role: 'annotation'}],
    ["7.08.2015", 0, 0, 0, 3, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 10, 10],
    ["6.08.2015", 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 6, 1, 0, 7, 18, 18],
    ["5.08.2015", 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 11, 11]
];
```

And added this to the options:

```
var options = {
    ...
    series: {
        9: {
            color: 'transparent',
            type: "bar",
            targetAxisIndex: 1,
            visibleInLegend: false
        }
    }
};
```

[Demo and code at JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hurik/f2cwmvg6/10/)

This makes the Total bar transparent, hide it in the legends and let it start from the zero point.

Dynamic version which takes the last data row for the annotations:

```
var series = {};
series[data.getNumberOfColumns() - 3] = {
    color: 'transparent',
    type: "bar",
    targetAxisIndex: 1,
    visibleInLegend: false
};

options["series"] = series;
```

[Demo and code at JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hurik/f2cwmvg6/9/)